# What is the formula for the distance of two points in general coordinates

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems

What is the distance between two points $A(x_1,y_1)$ and $B(x_2,y_2)$ given a metric $g_{xx},g_{xy},g_{yy}$ which depends on $x,y$?

**Edit**

In general, when the metric tensor. $\mathbf{g}$ is general, the problem consists of finding a geodesic passing through the two points and to work out the length of this piece of geodesic through $A$ and $B$. However, if $\mathbf{g}$ is the flat Euclidean metric, this is easy to find and we have
$$ \operatorname{d}(A,B) = \sqrt{(x_2 - x_1)^2 + (y_2 - y_1)^2}$$
Also when the metric is the Minkowski one, there exists a formula for the distance.

My question ha become therefore: under which hypothesis on the metric on a surface $S$ can I find a formula for the distance between two points?

Comment: So, we have a Riemann manifold structure on $\Bbb R^2$, don't we? Then we need to find *geodesics* and geodesic distance.

Comment: @Berci sort of, yes. But whilst we always say the distance is given by $ds^2 = g_{11}(x,y)dx^2 + 2g_{12}(x,y)dxdy + g_{22}(x,y)dy^2$, it is not totally straightforward how to apply this formula for two points let’s say in the plane. In other word, the question could be: how do you integrate this formula?

Comment: What is distance?  Presuming you mean the minimum then you have to take a path integral (path unknown) and minimize it.  I believe you want a geodesic?  You could examine https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/137422/geodesic-equation-from-euler-lagrange